# Get data from a Object datatype in python dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a DataFrame with Coordinates saved in the following format {"type":"Point","coordinates":[25.2484759,55.3525189]}.
It is saved as an object dtype. Please help me retrieving the coordinates from this column without iteration.

I am a beginner in coding ,but I do think that running a loop over this and splitting the data would be a unnecessary task.Hope you all could help me

This is what I thought
float(trip_data["pickuplocation"][0][31:-13]),float(trip_data["pickuplocation"][0][-12:-3])

I want coordinates to be saved as an array.
Sorry If I sound less technical.Please feel free to ask more details.

Comment: The data is stored in one column as an object. But when I try to a specific data it gets retrieved as a string object

Comment: Which is the best way to save coordinates so that I can use it to generate spatial graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use dataframes with spatial data you should might at the GeoPandas package.

To address the question, assuming the column is a string, you were quite close, you can get the coordinates without a loop using:

```
coord1 = trip_data["pickuplocation"].str[31:-13].astype(float)
coord2 = trip_data["pickuplocation"].str[-12:-3].astype(float)
```

You need to tell pandas to treat this object as a string to use string indexing, and then you tell it the series are floats with the astype.

Edit: A more reliable, if less safe (do not use this in production code because ast.literal_eval is not safe) approach might be to use ast though:

```
import ast 

coords = trip_data["pickuplocation"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["coordinates"])
```

You should then be able to index coords as a list.

Comment: Thank you so much @njwfish. I tried this and another issue popped up. I am afraid that the slicing wont work because the decimal point differs in some rows.Do we have any alternative for this .May be something like regex?

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: its possible you can also use json instead of ast (subbing it in in the lambda I wrote). This might be better!